# Disable Certain Firefox Plugins System-wide by Default

Tags: firefox

I have firefox installed system-wide for all our users.  Unfortunately the Adobe Reader Plug-in is rather flakey and doesn't work some of the time.  As a result I want to disable the plug-in by default for all our users, but still allow them to enable it if they want via the standard Tools->Add-ons->Plug-ins menu option.  How can I have this plug-ins enabled/disabled status be disabled by default?

I've been able to configure system-wide configurations before by setting preferences in the mozilla root folder file `defaults/pref/all.js`, but enabled/disabled plugins doesn't appear to be configured in the preferences.

[edit 1]: I found ['How to manage firefox plugins in pluginreg.dat file'](http://www.emanuelis.eu/2010/06/17/how-to-manage-firefox-plugins-in-pluginreg-dat-file/) which explained some of the formatting of the `pluginreg.dat` file.  From there I could see flags are masked as follows (from [nsPluginHostImpl.h](http://mxr.mozilla.org/seamonkey/source/modules/plugin/base/src/nsPluginHostImpl.h)):

```
#define NS_PLUGIN_FLAG_ENABLED 0x0001 // is this plugin enabled?
#define NS_PLUGIN_FLAG_OLDSCHOOL 0x0002 // is this a pre-xpcom plugin?
#define NS_PLUGIN_FLAG_FROMCACHE 0x0004 // this plugintag info was loaded from cache
#define NS_PLUGIN_FLAG_UNWANTED 0x0008 // this is an unwanted plugin
#define NS_PLUGIN_FLAG_BLOCKLISTED 0x0010 // this is a blocklisted plugin
```

But is there a way to add this to the defaults so that that NS_PLUGIN_FLAG_ENABLED is removed by default?

Answer (score 6):

The [plugins' settings](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=830267) are now integrated partially in [about:config](http://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config) as of Firefox 22, and fully in 23+. The key names are **plugin.state.*** where * denotes the [internal naming scheme used by Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=838290) for the discovered plugins. The values (integer) are 0 for disabled (**Never Activate** in Firefox **Tools** (Alt + T) > **Add-ons** > **Plugins**), 1 for click-to-play (**Ask to Activate**), and 2 for enabled (**Always Activate**). Firefox 22 has 0 and 2, and 23+ includes all the three states. The state **Ask to Activate** (1) is triggered after toggling **plugins.click_to_play** to true in **about:config**.

One way to get the correct names used by Firefox is from a reference/IT PC. Toggle the default states of all the discovered plugins (Firefox Tools (Alt + T) > Add-ons > Plugins) once, to reveal the corresponding **plugin.state.*** keys in **about:config**.

Using the [lock (policy) file](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Locking_preferences), **defaultPref()** or **pref()** can be used to set an initial **preference** i.e. nonmandatory - users may later change the initially set state of the plugin -, while **lockPref()** can be used to set a **policy** i.e mandatory - users cannot change the state.

e.g. **defaultPref("plugin.state.flash", 0);** to set an initial disabled state for the Flash plugin which users may change, or **lockPref("plugin.state.flash", 0);** to lock the state.

To also include **Ask to Activate** (1):

**defaultPref("plugins.click_to_play", true);** OR **lockPref("plugins.click_to_play", true);**
**defaultPref("plugin.state.flash", 1);**

[about:config Entries](http://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config_entries), [Config Descriptions addon](https://services.addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/discovery/addon/config-descriptions/)